# how can I use an adapter to get a specific element of an object if the listview is populated using data coming from server side

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` which is populated using data coming from serverside(reftrofit) how can I use an `Adapter` to get a specific element of the object? The expandable list view contains parent and child elements. When I click on the child element I would like to extract an ID(SensorID) that is associated with that child element.

I Have an `Adapter`where I am attempting to extract the ID from the object but I am unable to. I noticed that for an array `Adapter`the `getItemAtPosition()` method is used to get an index then extract an element from the object(sensorID). 
I am however not sure if this is the same method that should be used for an `ExpandableListAdapter` because I have seen snippets of code where the method `getChild()` is used.

The error I get everytime on click reads

> ExpandableListConnector cannot be cast to
>   com.xera.deviceinsight.home.ExpandableListAdapter

**The method in question**

```
 private void load(View view)
   {

      expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
      prepareListData();
      listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
      expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
      expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            System.err.println("child clicked");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "child clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ItemClickedEvent(SensorInformationChildFragment.TAB_CALL));
            ExpandableListAdapter adapter = (ExpandableListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult deviceSensor = (OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult) adapter.getChild(groupPosition , childPosition);
            sensorID = deviceSensor.SensorID;

             ReportingGroup.get(childPosition);

            return true;
         }
      });
   }
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {

   private Context _context;
   private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
   // child data in format of header title, child title
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
   public List<OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult> Items;

   public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
      this._context = context;
      this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
      this._listDataChild = listChildData;
   }

   @Override
   public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
      return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
   }

   @Override
   public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return childPosition;
   }

   public OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult getItemAtPosition(int index)
   {
      return getItemAtPosition(index);
      //return this.getItem(index);
      //return this.getItem(index);
      //return index;
      //return this.get
      //return OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult.
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
      OrganisationDeviceSensorsResult deviceSensor = getItemAtPosition(childPosition);
      if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
      }

      TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

      txtListChild.setText(childText);
      return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
      return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
      return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
   }

   @Override
   public int getGroupCount() {
      return this._listDataHeader.size();
   }

   @Override
   public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
      return groupPosition;
   }

   @Override
   public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
      if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
      }

      TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
      lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
      lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

      return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
      return true;
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had more or less your situation, I do it with this code in the Activity where the listview is placed:

```
        contactListExpandable = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);

        contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, chatGroupList);
        contactListExpandable.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);
    contactListExpandable.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            ChatContact contact = chatGroupList.get(groupPosition).getContacts().get(childPosition);
            launchChat(contact, null, false, "");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In my case, I get the child Object to launch a chat, etc, in your case you will be abre to obtain the Sensor object and do your stuff

=== ChatGroup ===

```
public class ChatGroup  implements Comparable{
    final public String name;
    private List<ChatContact> contacts;

    public ChatGroup(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addContact(ChatContact contact){
        this.contacts.add(contact);
    }

    public List<ChatContact> getContacts(){
        return this.contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        ChatGroup cg = (ChatGroup)o;
        return name.compareTo(cg.name);
    }
}
```

=== ChatContact.java ===

```
    public class ChatContact implements Parcelable, Comparable {
        final public String name;
        final public String jid;
        public Status status;

        public ChatContact(String name, String jid) {
            this.name = name;
            this.jid = jid;
        }
        .....getters/setters/etc.....
   }
```

Comment: hi what is chatgroupList in your case? I have this line of code that references  activity instead. `listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);`

Comment: @Zidane sorry for delay. My chatGroupList, is the list I give to adapter, that contains the objects to show. In your case, you have 2 ist, listDataHeader, and listDataChild

Comment: that getContacts method is the only thing confusing me otherwise everything else makes sense

Comment: could you give me a link to an example perhaps?

Comment: @Zidane I added the class ChatGroup and ChatContact. variable chatGroupList is --> List<ChatGroup> chatGroupList = ....; so, what I have is a list of ChatGroup objects. When I click on the child, I get, firts to wich object refers (parent), then with the method getContacts , i get the contacts of that group, and select the child in position.